# Background Doesn't Cover Scrollable Area

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="fixed-area">
    <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body, body * {
    z-index: 3;
}
div.container {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000000;
    z-index: 1;
}
div.fixed-area {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
div.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 1500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

The container (black) and fixed-area (yellow) divs do not expand with the content div (red) to cover the scrollable area.  When scrollbar is used to view the bottom part of the content, a white background takes the place of the container and fixed-area divs. **How can make the container and fixed-area divs expand to cover all background of the content, even when scrolled down?**

Comment: It's because you've done `100%` which is `100%` of window, not document. Set it to the same amount of pixels your longest document is.

Comment: why not set the `height:1500px` for the fixed area? you are setting its height to `100% of viewport's height`

Comment: Please, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.com). It's much better. Perhaps [codepen](http://codepen.io) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com), please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `.container` should have a minimum height of 100%, but should grow with the `.fixed-area` container, use:

```
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/gopeter/B2Ljt/4/ (shows how `min-height` works) and http://jsfiddle.net/gopeter/B2Ljt/3/ (shows how `.container` grows with `.fixed-area`)

Answer (score 1):

Change container height to `auto`

Answer (score 1):

Change to your container to this CSS

```
div.container {
height: auto;
position: relative;
background-color: #000000;
z-index: 1;
}
```

You had to change your container's height to `auto;`

Answer (score 1):

You made the container's height 100%, which you didn't want. Simply remove this style.

[`JSFiddle demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/hXyFP/)